# Can you use advanced sheets service with spreadsheets.currentonly scope?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have found using the [advanced sheets service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to be very useful, mainly due to its vastly improved performance.

I have made a Google Sheet which will be copied by people outside of my organisation who will then want to use the attached script. This triggers the "unauthorized app" warning for them since the advanced service sets the scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive by default. Since I am only accessing the current file, albeit by referencing its id in my functions, it feels as though it should be possible to make it work with only the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly scope.

When "forcing" the scope to be narrowed using the appscript.json file I get the error "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Is there a workaround to solve this problem or am I out of luck?

Any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding these scopes: [Google Sheets API, v4](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets)

Comment: In the meantime a more comprehensive Q/A has been posted on this very topic - [Use the Advanced Sheets Service with permissions only for current sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76617090/use-the-advanced-sheets-service-with-permissions-only-for-current-sheet). Voting to close this one.